# Xcode 4 Memory Leak Instrument how to get line of code where leak occurred

Tags: ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks

I'm attempting to use the Memory Leak instrument in Xcode 4 with iOS 5.1 (ARC enabled) and I am spotting memory leaks, but how the hell do I get to the line of code causing the leak? I've read a few tutorials on this but it seems to be an older version of the instrumentation tool because when I click on the extended detail tab and double click on items in the backtrace I'm presented only with useless assembly code. Also none of the items on the stacktrace are any of the classes that I've written. Am I missing something?

Comment: if you're going to vote me down at least tell me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code leaks memory, you will see your relevant methods in the details tab, right where you are looking. They are displayed in black as opposed to methods in the APIs which are gray. You can't look into API Methods of course, hence the assembly code. If there is really something wrong in your code, set the slider on the bottom of the tab on the rightmost position and you should see the concerned methods.

If still none of them are in your code, you probably just don't leak anything. (There are actually not many scenarios in which ARC-Code can leak memory. Retain cycles are probably the most common one) I stumbles over one or two cases in which an API was 'leaking' memory. There is really nothing you can do about it and most likely, it's just a false positive anyway rather than a real leak. If you are only 'leaking' a few bytes, I wouldn't worry about it.